# For CSS, if we set display to table, table-row, or table-cell, then why don't we outright use <table><tr><td> to do it?

Tags: css, forms, responsive-design

This is for Responsive Web Design, and I am looking in some existing code for how a form is done.

A coworker set the container `div` of First Name label and `<input>` and an "error message" under the input box, using CSS `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.  He mentioned that it worked fine on Chrome and Firefox but had something weird on IE 8.  Please see the simplified version on http://jsfiddle.net/DzEww/7/

This is so that the form can show nicely on any desktop browser and on mobile device that may be merely 320 pixel wide.

1. First, I wonder, is this a preferred method to do Responsive Web Design?
2. I wonder if we use CSS `table` and `table-cell`, then why don't we actually outright use HTML `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` to do it?  (example: http://jsfiddle.net/DzEww/12/) It feels a bit strange to use CSS table display to show it and expect it to be a structure of a table but not mark it up as a table.  If we do expect the structure to be a table, then why don't we just directly use `<table><tr><td>` to mark it up?

(Note that this form is really a good tabular of form labels and form fields, so using `<table><tr><td>` might actually make a lot of sense.)

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

Comment: This is one of those debates that never seems to go away. I use css for tables, but there are no real benefits to doing this! I guess it boils down to user preference.

Answer (score 0):

The **table element** in `HTML` **is a semantic structure** to describes what data is. The table element should be used if the data is tabular (normally the datas that can be stored in a spreadsheet), it probably needs marking up as a table in HTML.

While **`table` value of the `display` property**, is simply a tool to set look of something like table in the browser, it **has no semantic meaning**. This technique has the potential of for creating complex grid layouts with ease.

Using a table element for layout tells a user-agent, “This data is tabular.” Using a bunch of divs that have the display property set to `table` and `table-cell` says nothing to that user-agent other than asking it to render them visually in a certain way, if it’s capable of doing so.

Of course, we should also take care not to use `display: table;` on a bunch of div elements when what we really have is tabular data!